Does $ f(x) = 2x $ on $[0,1]$ contradict the exercise about compact manifolds and critical points?
I found the following exercise in Ana Cannas da Silva's Lectures on Symplectic Geometry.

Let $ X $ be a compact manifold (not just a single point), and let$ f \in C^\infty(X) $. Define $X_{df} = \{(x, df(x)) \mid x \in X\} $, and let $ X_0 $ denote the zero section of the cotangent bundle. The exercise asks to show that: $ \#(X_{df} \cap X_0) \geq 2. $

Now, consider the manifold $[0, 1]$, which is compact, and the smooth function $ f(x) = 2x $. Here the derivative $df(x) = 2 \, dx$ never vanishes, so $ X_{df} \cap X_0 = \emptyset $.

Is $[0, 1]$ really a manifold? Usually, such a thing would be called a "manifold with boundary"

Don't we use the term 'manifold' to describe manifolds with and without boundaries in an inclusive way?

Not necessarily. If no further explanation, then "manifold" basically means "manifold without boundary".

$2x$ is a map from $[0,1]\to[0,2]$ so are you meaning to use an isomorphism between the two? Confused in what sense $2x$ is a map on $[0,1]$.

$2x$ is regarded as a 0-form on $[0,1]$

A compact manifold is always assumed to have no boundary unless it is stated explicitly that it is a compact manifold with boundary.
